# Login con bloqueo de usuarios bajo 3 intentos fallidos

Tags: php, login, validación

hice esto pero me actualiza solo cuando la sesión es exitosa y le suma 1 al campo intentos. Lo que necesito es que cuando los datos sean erróneos haga ese proceso ¿que tengo mal?

```
if ($resultado !== false) {
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario.$resultado["usuario"];
    $_SESSION['tabla'] = $resultado['tabla'];
    $_SESSION['numero'] = $numero.$resultado['numero'];
    $_SESSION['estado'] = $estado.$resultado['estado'];
    $_SESSION['intentos'] = $intentos.$resultado['intentos'];
    $_SESSION['codigo'] = $codigo.$resultado['codigo'];
    $_SESSION['rut'] = $rut.$resultado['rut'];
    $_SESSION['grupo'] = $grupo.$resultado['grupo'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email.$resultado['email'];
    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $identificador.$resultado['id_usuario'];
    $_SESSION['hora_entrada'].$hora_entrada.$resultado['hora_entrada'];
    $nStatement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO movimientos (id_usuario, tipo_movimiento, accedio_a) VALUES (:id_usuario, 1, 1)");
    $nStatement->execute(array("id_usuario"=> $resultado["id_usuario"]));

    header('Location: index.php');

} else {
    //$errores .= '<li>Número telefónico, Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos</li>';
    $execucion = $conexion->prepare("UPDATE usuarios SET intentos = 1 WHERE id_usuario = :id_usuario");
    $execucion->execute(array("id_usuario"=> $resultado["id_usuario"]));

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Lo siento!","Número telefónico, Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectos","error");';
    echo '}, 1000); </script>';
}
```

Comment: Daniel, siempre es más útil pegar el código que una imagen con tu código.

Comment: El problema es que estas incrementando los intentos cuando el inicio de sesión es exitoso y no cuando sea fallido, debes poner tu incrementador en el else donde tienes `"errores .= "<li>Número ....... "`

Comment: Acá esta el código por favor si alguien me ayuda la tabla acceso que esta en al coodigo es una vista creada en mysql y tengo entendido que no inserta datos solos los muestra por que es la union de dos tablas

Comment: no me deja pegar el código

Comment: Edita la pregunta inical.

Comment: la edite pero cuando guardo me marca error

Comment: dame tu face para que me ayudes por ahí porfa

Comment: Realmente no lo uso pero en todo caso; se supone que esta es una plataforma para ayuda entre programadores, y facebook una red social para hacer amigos. edita tu pregunta para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: la edito y luego que apreto por que aprete los corchetes y me dice inserte codigo lo inserte y sale error

Answer (score 1):

Como te han comentado, el error es que sumas intentos fallidos cuando en realidad son exitosos.

Esto está mal

```
if ($resultado !== false) {
 .....
 $_SESSION['intentos'] = $intentos.$resultado['intentos']++;
 .....
} else {
 .....
 .....
}
```

Debe ser así:

```
if ($resultado !== false) {
 .....
 .....
} else {
 .....
 .....
 $_SESSION['intentos'] = $intentos.$resultado['intentos']++;
}
```